# How do i retain the data value of static variable despite the program restarting?

Tags: c++, c, mql4, mql5

I have a static variables on several of my functions, how do i retain the value of these static variables when an unexpected restart in program occurs?

Comment: Write value to a file.  Read it on startup.

Comment: You need some way to dump the state into persistent storage (a file)

Comment: You can write the variables to a file. The problem, however, would be exactly when to write the values since what you are trying to mitigate is an 'unexpected' restart.

Comment: How do the values get there in the beginning?

Comment: What is an `unexpected` restart? Either the program is shutdown or not. If it is exited by the programs control flow, you know when it exits. If it terminates because of an exception, you need an exception handler. In this case, writing may or may not work, because the program can potentially be unstable at that point. You could also write a `savepoint` at certain strategic points in your code.

Comment: File, database, and unobtanium are the three most reasonable answers.

Comment: Some operating systems have a *registry* which you may be able to use.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this in standard C++. However, there is a way of doing it with OS-specific tools, and most often, the best tool is a memory backed by permanent storage - a memory-mapped file.

All OSes I have ever worked with support memory-mapped files, although specifics might differ between OSes.

Unfortunately, using conventional files to store variables like that is quite inconvenient, as you'd have to explicitly save the value every time you change it, and make sure the buffers are flushed - otherwise you can't guarantee that the value is preserved after ungraceful exit - and that would be quite detrimental to performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MQL4 or MQL5 (which I assume you are by the tags on your post), simply use GlobalVariables.

MQL4: https://book.mql4.com/variables/globals

MQL5: https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/globals